# Get coordinates of First Person Control

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three.js and I would like to get the coordinates of the first person view to use in  an keyboard event.
How do I get the coordinates? I tried to:

```
controls.position.x
```

But this is undefined.
I set up my FPControl with this code:

```
var controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
controls.movementSpeed = 2.5;
controls.lookSpeed = 0.075;
controls.lookVertical = false;
controls.noFly = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at `camera.position.x` instead.